# How do I combine unique values from a list of tuples?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have 2 lists (from an excel file) with one containing the names of products and the others containing numbers.

Example Excel File:

[image: Example Excel Document]

Which means I have 2 lists - ripped with xlrd.col_values():

```
products = ['Product1','Product1','Product1','Product2','Product2','Product2']
values = [1,-1,0,2,4,-1]
```

The end result I would like is this:

```
format = [['Product1', [1,-1,0]],['Product2', [2,4,-1]]]
```

I have attempted to do this using zip():

```
zip_list = list(zip(products, values))
```

However this returned:

```
[('Product1', 1), ('Product1', -1), ('Product1', 0), ('Product2', 2), ('Product2', 4), ('Product2', -1)]
```

Would anyone know how to get the desired format? - I am using python3.

Comment: You got that from `zip()` because that is exactly what it does.

Comment: @pstatix ,Yes, sorry I should've mentioned that I've never used zip before and was just posting it there in case there was a way to use the zip() function to create it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary (ideal: `collections.defaultdict`) to collect your data and then use the `dict.items()` to create your format:

```
from collections import defaultdict

products = ['Product1','Product1','Product1','Product2','Product2','Product2']
values = [1,-1,0,2,4,-1]

d = defaultdict(list)
# accumulate your data
for prod,val in zip(products,values):
    d[prod].append(val)

print(d)   

# convert dict.items() to your wanted format    
format = [list(i) for i in d.items()] 
print(format)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Product1': [1, -1, 0], 'Product2': [2, 4, -1]})

[['Product1', [1, -1, 0]], ['Product2', [2, 4, -1]]]
```

Using `defaultdict(list)` is preferable over `dict.setdefault(key,[])` or using `try: except:` or testing if `key in dict` because it is overall faster (builtin optimizations) then any of the other methods.

Doku:

- [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)
- [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

---

You could also leverage [itertools.groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) wich operates on sorted data (yours *is* sorted) to get to the same results:

```
from itertools import groupby

grped = groupby( zip(products,values), lambda x:x[0]) # group by 1st value

l = []
for g in grped:
    l.append([g[0],list(val for _,val in g[1])])      # extract 2nd value from grouping

print(l) # [['Product1', [1, -1, 0]], ['Product2', [2, 4, -1]]]
```

Using `groupby` on this list creates the same partitioning because it is sorted - if it was not sorted you'd get different results.

Comment: I think `itertools.groupby` is the canonical answer to this question, I would even consider listing it first. Also, I might change "sorted" to "grouped." The data do not need to be sorted - the only requirement is that the values in the first column are grouped (i.e. not interwoven).

Comment: Nit, `l = [[g[0], [v for _, v in g[1]] for g in grped]` might be more concise.

Comment: @JaredGoguen groupby needs sorted data - it will only create groups of consecutive values: `groupby( zip([1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1],[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]) ==> [[1, [1, 1, 1]], [2, [2, 2, 2]], [1, [3, 3, 3]]]` will create 2 groups for key `1` - the defaultdict does not need pre-sorting: [[1, [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3]], [2, [2, 2, 2]]]

Comment: Using `[2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3]` as the entries in the first list should work fine - these are not sorted

Comment: @Jared - they do not need to be sorted - they do not share the same key That is the point - for groupby to group _all_ of one key into one grouping they need to be sorted - the dict aproach does not. So if you do not want the same key in different groupings you need to sort first for groupby which adds complexity to the solution - if you are fine with having the same key in different groupings when other groups are between consecutive key-stretches you do not ... hence it depends what you want and what you need. Both approaches have value depending on what you want as result.

Comment: Thank you very much, I ended up using this in one of my codes - Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1):

Since dictionary comprehension is not good for aggregation, just use a linear time loop:

```
prods = {}
for item in zip(products, values):
    prod, val = item
    try:
        prods[prod].append(val)
    except KeyError:
        prods[prod] = [val]

# Sample
>>> prods = {}
>>> for item in zip(products, values):
    prod, val = item
    try:
        prods[prod].append(val)
    except KeyError:
        prods[prod] = [val]     
>>> prods
{'Product1': [1, -1, 0], 'Product2': [2, 4, -1]}
```

I understand you wanted a format of `[['ProductN', [ ]]` but I think a dictionary is a better choice.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works really well, if I were to have more than 2 arrays, For example getting: {Product:[[array1],[array2]]} instead.... Your answer works really well though...

Comment: @wowcha Your original question doesnt ask for something where you would need two lists per key.